# how to get an input from the keyboard without interrupting code? i.e. checking keyboard status

Tags: assembly, x86, keyboard, dos, bios

currently i am using int 16,1. for some reason in my code, the second time i use int 16,1(in a game loop), it stays on the same value i pressed the first time, regardless if it still pressed or not. i have given up and i am asking if there is another way to get keyboard status without stopping the code.

i have tried debugging it for multiple hours, running turbo debugger, ran it through multiple teachers, no source for the problem.

this is a gist for the full code if needed
https://gist.github.com/yuvyuv2005/09ab20fd321c70ce598d6bb4151990cf#file-nole-asm

```
    Proc Get_Input

    xor ax, ax
    mov ah, 1h
    int 16h
    jz noInp


    push ax
    call Check_Input
    noInp:

    ret
    endp Get_Input



    Key_Pressed EQU [bp+4]
    Proc Check_Input
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
    mov [RightMole], 0




    mov ax, Key_Pressed
    mov [Num_Pressed], al



    Num7:
    mov al, [Num_Pressed]
    sub al, "0"

    cmp al, 7
    JNE Num4



    cmp [MoleHole], 0
    JNE Num4

    push [word ptr MoleHole]
    call Remove_Mole
    inc [Scorearr+6] 
    mov [RightMole], 1

    Num4:
    mov al, [Num_Pressed]
    sub al, "0"
    cmp al, 4
    JNE Num1


cmp [MoleHole], 1
JNE Num1
push [word ptr MoleHole]
call Remove_Mole
inc [Scorearr+6] 
mov [RightMole], 1


Num1:
mov al, [Num_Pressed]
sub al, "0"
cmp al, 1
JNE Num8

cmp [MoleHole], 2
JNE Num8
push [word ptr MoleHole]
call Remove_Mole
inc [Scorearr+6] 
mov [RightMole], 1


Num8:
mov al, [Num_Pressed]
sub al, "0"
cmp al, 8
JNE Num5

cmp [MoleHole], 3
JNE Num5
push [word ptr MoleHole]
call Remove_Mole
inc [Scorearr+6] 
mov [RightMole], 1


Num5:
mov al, [Num_Pressed]
sub al, "0"
cmp al, 5
JNE Num2

cmp [MoleHole], 4
JNE Num2
push [word ptr MoleHole]
call Remove_Mole
inc [Scorearr+6] 
mov [RightMole], 1


Num2:
mov al, [Num_Pressed]
sub al, "0"
cmp al, 2
JNE Num9

cmp [MoleHole], 5
JNE Num9
push [word ptr MoleHole]
call Remove_Mole
inc [Scorearr+6] 
mov [RightMole], 1


Num9:
mov al, [Num_Pressed]
sub al, "0"
cmp al, 9
JNE Num6

cmp [MoleHole], 6
JNE Num6
push [word ptr MoleHole]
call Remove_Mole
inc [Scorearr+6] 
mov [RightMole], 1


Num6:
mov al, [Num_Pressed]
sub al, "0"
cmp al, 6
JNE Num3

cmp [MoleHole], 7
JNE Num3
push [word ptr MoleHole]
call Remove_Mole
inc [Scorearr+6] 
mov [RightMole], 1


Num3:
mov al, [Num_Pressed]
sub al, "0"
cmp al, 3
JNE finish

cmp [MoleHole], 8
JNE finish
push [word ptr MoleHole]
call Remove_Mole
inc [Scorearr+6]
mov [RightMole], 1
```

actual game loop

```
Game_Loop:



    call DrawMole

    ; push offset Scorearr
    ; push 0
    ; push 2
    ; call Print_str
    ; add [Scorearr+6], "0"

    ;cx is how many times i want to wait 0.55 seconds before the player loses. the number here is very high for debugging reasons, ususally its a lot lower.
    mov cx, 640

    KeyPressLoop:
        push cx



        call Get_Input
        cmp [RightMole], 1
        JE Game_Loop
        pop cx
        push 1
        call Delay


    Loop KeyPressLoop
    jmp GameOver
```

this is the delay function, might be something wrong with it too although from what i know its perfectly fine.

```
    proc delay
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
    push ax
    push cx
    push es

    ticks equ [bp + 4]
    clock equ es:6Ch

    mov ax, 40h
    mov es, ax
    mov ax, [clock]

    mov cx, ticks
    delayLoop:
        mov ax, [clock]
    tick:
            cmp ax, [clock]
            je tick
        loop delayLoop


    pop es
    pop cx
    pop ax
    pop bp
    ret 2
    endp delay
```

this is code for a whac a mole game, hence all the mole related ints.

this code is the one checking the input of the user, using numpad. from what ive read int 16, 1 puts the ASCII value of the number pressed in AL. (the game is played using numpad) if you are running the code, turn on numlock only after opening the emulator. on dosbox the numlock only applies after opening dosbox. the first time a mole should be whacked, the program works. the moment the second mole shows up, the code goes into an infinite loop in the last button pressed in the Check Input command. i found that out using a debug_rect proc. how the game should actually work is if the player pressed the right number on the numpad, the game removes that mole and draws a new one randomly. 
it works for the first mole, but gets stuck in an infinite loop somewhere after drawing the second one.

Comment: I haven't really looked at the code but are you aware that if you use Int 16h/AH=1h that it peeks at the keyboard without actually removing the character from the keyboard buffer? You will want to call Int 16h/AH=0 after detecting a keystroke with Int 16h/AH=1 so that the character is removed from the buffer. If you don't it will stay in the buffer and will be repeatedly retrieved by future Int 16h/AH=1 calls.